# MFCC in speech recognition

Tags: signal-processing, fft, speech-recognition, voice-recognition, mfcc

I spent whole last week to search on MFCC and related issues. Now I can get MFCC features from a .wav file in a 2-dimensional vector, coff[56][12], let's say. 12 is the number of coefficents I want to extract and 56 is the number of frames.
According to several documents I read, we can use above 12 coefficents to recognize speech (in particular, I want to recognize word "one", "two"... to "ten"). But now I get 56 of 12-cofficents, so which one among 56 frames I should use?

If I got something wrong, please help me!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are skipping some crucial steps. Let me briefly explain how it should work. Speech data is initially a discrete signal. You cut it into pieces called "frames" so small that each piece hopefully contain no more than a single phone. Often frames are overlapped to not to lost any vital information. Then you extract features - MFCCs and using Hidden Makov Model search for the most probable word that comprises a number of frames. At this time you also need a dictionary of words pronunciation and the acoustic model. On the next level you use a language model that describes sentences the words can be constructed into, and get the final hypothesis. This is extremely abstract description, so need to review each step of decoding on a closer extent.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. You mean after extracting MFCC features I have to use Hidden Makov Model to find in the "dictionary of words" a word that is the most probable?

Comment: Dictionary tells how words are constructed from syllables. Here is a paste from a real dictionary: hello [HH AH L OW], hello(2) [HH EH L OW]. Now using MFCCs and the acoustic model you can obtain probability that a certain sequence of frames corresponds to a particular word. Take a look at http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/ You would be interested in sphinxbase and pocketsphinx in particular. The formed is an asset library for speech recognition, and the later is end-to-end speech decoder. Also you can read "Spoken Language Processing" which is quite comprehensive.

Comment: @AlexanderSolovets I used Librosa to extract MFCC features . My Audio wav file is 22 mins (1320  secs) .  I extracted 20 MFCC coefficients, which gives me frames of (20 X 56829) . How does the number 56829 comes here? Is there any calculation for it ?

Comment: I don't know librosa's configuration, but usually one frame is 25ms long, and frames overlap by 10 ms, e.g. the first frame is at [0; 25], the second one is at [10; 35], and so on.

Comment: @Rangooski librosa calculates mfcc per 'frame' .This frame is determined by hop_length and SR. `frame_size= hop_length/sr` and this defaults to 512/22050 ~~ 23ms. So mfcc are calculated every 23ms. 


your audio is 1320 seconds long. The mfcc shape is 20X56829. 
20 is the number of features. 56829 are the number of time frames. i.e your audio was divided into 56829 frames.  

1320/56829 = 0.023227577 seconds i.e ~~ 23ms. Hope this helps.